# Adding cases by group in SAS

Tags: merge, sas, dataset

I have an SAS dataset in a long format. The intervention program started from 2014 Spring semester, and it has been on until 2017 Spring semester. So there has been 7 semesters (2014 Spring and Fall, 2015 Spring and Fall, 2016 Spring and Fall, 2017 Spring).

Not everyone participated in all 7 semesters though. Some participated once and never came back, some participated more than twice but not necessarily two semesters in a low.

So each individual has a different number of cases. For someone who participated twice, for example, has 2 rows, some with 5 participations have 5 rows.

I want everyone has 7 rows in the dataset for some reason. 
What could be the best way of programming to do this in SAS?

I would really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Are you saying you want the table to have seven rows, one for each semester, and then a column for each individual?

Comment: In the dataset, I want seven rows for each individual. As far as I understand, I don't want a column for each individual. The dataset would look like this: Spring 2014 / Fall 2014 / Spring 2015 / Fall 2015 / Spring 2016 / Fall 2016 / Spring 2017. And there will be columns for variables in each semester. Does it make sense? I don't know how to draw a table in this website... ! Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

PROC EXPAND is probably the most direct way to do this, although it has the limitation that it won't extrapolate beyond the observed start/end of the range, and it expects regular intervals (or a lot more work to define intervals).

```
proc expand data=your_data out=expanded_data from=semiyear extrapolate method=none;
  by student;
  id semester_date;
run;
```

That relies on semester_date being a date variable corresponding generally to the start of each half-year.

Perhaps more easily in this case, you could use the `printmiss` option in `proc tabulate`, which would generate a table pretty easily.

```
ods output table=out_table;
proc tabulate data=your_data;
  class student semester;
   tables student,semester/printmiss misstext=' ';
run;
ods output close;
```

Then merge that back to the main dataset, this will have a row for every student*semester combination.

Comment: Thanks! Somebody suggested a syntax using Proc SQL and I find it very easy and simple. But I still really appreciate your work as well! I didn't know about Proc Expand and I usually don't use Proc Tabulate, so I learned a lot. I will post the solution soon.